# How to have two or more features in the same layer with openlayers?

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to put more then one geometry in the same Layer.
But I can't get it to work.

The map shows but only the last geometry show up on the map.

```
  var mupp3 = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [
                    new ol.Feature({
                            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([18.271815, 59.669000])),
                            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([18.271915, 59.668000]))



  })
            ]
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one geometry per feature:

```
var mupp3 = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [
                    new ol.Feature({
                            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([18.271815, 59.669000]))
                    }),
                    new ol.Feature({
                            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([18.271915, 59.668000]))
                    })
            ]
    })
  });
```